# Is there any standard javascript function to convert string into phone number format and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, function, phone-number

I need two functions one which will convert string to phone number format and other which will convert phone number to string. Are there any standard JS functions available for this?

Comment: I'd just like to mention that "phone number format" is highly ambiguous and means different things in different cultures/countries.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: Or even within a country, yeah, when you think of things like extensions. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. You'll have to write one or find one. It will probably use a combination of various [`String` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and/or [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).